# Как в Inno-Setup получить версию установленного msi продукта?

Tags: inno-setup, msi

Требуется в скрипте Inno Setup получить версию уже установленного продукта по `ProductUpgradeCode` и отобразить её.

Получить id продукта по `ProductUpgradeCode` можно при помощи `MsiEnumRelatedProducts`.

Далее версию продукта можно при помощи `MsiGetProductInfo`.

```
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

const
  ERROR_SUCCESS = $00000000;
  ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY = $00000008;
  ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = $00000057;
  ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = $00000103;
  ERROR_BAD_CONFIGURATION = $0000064A;

function MsiEnumRelatedProducts(lpUpgradeCode: string; dwReserved: DWORD; iProductIndex: DWORD; lpProductBuf: string): UINT;
  external 'MsiEnumRelatedProducts{#AW}@msi.dll stdcall';


function MsiGetProductInfo(szProduct: string; szProperty: string; lpValueBuf: string; pcchValueBuf: DWORD): UINT;
  external 'MsiGetProductInfo{#AW}@msi.dll stdcall';

function CheckPreviousProductInstance(upgradeCode: string; var previousVersion: string): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
  productBuf: string;
  versionBuf: string;
  pcchValueBuf: DWORD;
  resultCode: UINT;
begin
  Result := True;

  i := 0;
  SetLength(productBuf, 39);

  if MsiEnumRelatedProducts(upgradeCode, 0, i, productBuf) <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
  begin
    result := false;
    exit;
  end;

  MsgBox(productBuf, mbInformation, MB_OK);

  resultCode := MsiGetProductInfo(productBuf, 'INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING', versionBuf, pcchValueBuf);
  MsgBox(IntToStr(Integer(resultCode)), mbInformation, MB_OK);
  if MsiGetProductInfo(productBuf, 'INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING', versionBuf, pcchValueBuf) <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
  begin
    result := false;
    exit;
  end;

  MsgBox(versionBuf, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  MsgBox(IntToStr(Integer(pcchValueBuf)), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  result := true;
end;
```

`MsiGetProductInfo` возвращает $0000648.

Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Inno Setup Unicode получилось так:

```
const // Full list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376931(v=vs.85).aspx
  ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
  INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING = 'VersionString';

function MsiEnumRelatedProducts(lpUpgradeCode: string; dwReserved: DWORD; iProductIndex: DWORD; lpProductBuf: string): UINT;
  external 'MsiEnumRelatedProductsW@msi.dll stdcall';

function MsiGetProductInfo(szProduct: string; szProperty: String; lpValueBuf: String; var pcchValueBuf: DWORD): UINT;
  external 'MsiGetProductInfoW@msi.dll stdcall';

function GetPreviousProduct(UpgradeCode: string; var PreviousProductId: string; var PreviousProductVersion: string): Boolean;
var
  ProductBuf: string;
  VersionBuf: String;
  PcchValueBuf: DWORD;
begin
  SetLength(ProductBuf, 39);
  if MsiEnumRelatedProducts(upgradeCode, 0, 0, ProductBuf) <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
  begin
    PreviousProductId := '';
    PreviousProductVersion := '';
    Result := false;
    exit;
  end;

  SetLength(VersionBuf, 255);
  PcchValueBuf := Length(VersionBuf);
  if MsiGetProductInfo(ProductBuf, INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING, VersionBuf, PcchValueBuf) <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
  begin
    MsgBox('The VersionString is not received.', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    Abort();
    exit;
  end;

  SetLength(VersionBuf, PcchValueBuf);

  PreviousProductId := ProductBuf;
  PreviousProductVersion := VersionBuf;
  Result := true;
end;
```